# .Net Core Redirecting Url with Question Mark

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, redirect, asp.net-core

I am trying to redirect old URLs to new ones by using rewriter inside the middleware.

```
...
// Inside configure
var rewrite = new RewriteOptions().AddRedirect("oldUrl", "newUrl");
app.UseRewriter(rewrite);
...
```

Although I can't seem to redirect the paths with query parameters. Having a question mark in the URL breaks it.

**Works:**

```
Activity/location=&sub_category_ids=104&date_start=&date_end=
```

**Doesn't work:**

```
Activity/?location=&sub_category_ids=104&date_start=&date_end=
Activity/\\?location=&sub_category_ids=104&date_start=&date_end=
```

Using .Net Core 2.2

**Minimal Reproducible Example:**

1. Create an empty .net core application
2. Open up Startup.cs
3. Add the lines above to the configure method.
4. Use a URL with query parameter which involves having a question mark in the string; like films/?location=123.
5. Run the application and navigate to films/?location=123.

Comment: @mjwills You could clone [this repo](https://github.com/TahirNaushad/Fiver.Asp.UrlRewriting) and change the redirect url (at Startup:21) to something with question mark. Like "films/?location=123"

Comment: A [mcve] will be inside your question. It won't involve downloading / cloning random repos.

Comment: If you are looking to add query string parameters, I don't think those two methods (`AddRedirect` and  `AddRewrite`) are the ones you want to use as they expect controllers and actions rather than query string parameters. See [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.rewrite.rewriteoptions?view=aspnetcore-2.2#extension-methods) for more details

Comment: @mjwills Check out my latest edit.

Comment: @JamieTaylor _AddRedirect_ method accepts 2 strings one for input as regex and the other for output already. The output works seamlessly, but the only problem is using the question marks.

Comment: @starkm What's the expected behavior? Your code redirects fine for me.

Comment: @itminus Does it work for the cases that says **"Doesn't work"** inside the question?

Comment: @starkm  For me,  a request of `GET /films/?location=&sub_category_ids=104&date_start=&date_end=` will be redirected to `/movies?location=&sub_category_ids=104&date_start=&date_end=` .

Comment: @itminus Could you share your _AddRedirect_ method with us?

Comment: @starkm I just git clone your [code](https://github.com/TahirNaushad/Fiver.Asp.UrlRewriting) without any change.

Comment: @itminus I want to redirect exact this url: "Activity/location=&sub_category_ids=104&date_start=&date_end=" to something else. Not all the urls start with _Activity_ path.

Comment: @starkm what if an user sends request to `Activity/location=&sub_category_ids=105&date_start=` (without `date_end` and also changing the`sub_category_ids=105`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195043/discussion-between-itminus-and-starkm).